# .NET Google Docs API Authentication (without user interaction)

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth, google-api

Please would someone point me in the right direction?

I am working on a hosted application that runs periodically and needs to authenticate with Google before doing stuff with the DocumentsListAPI

The key point is that there is no user present to handle redirects etc.

Ideally, I would like to use the .NET libraries (DotNetOpenAuth and google-gdata)

I'm happy to do the leg-work if some knowledgeable person would just give me a shove down the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get a [Application Specific Password](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1032419). What will need to happen is you will log in once manually, then a [generate a application specific password](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens)  tied to the account you logged in with, after that you can just pass the username and the application specific password to the API requests your program makes and it should not need the extra user interaction you are concerned about.